# Retrieve Image from Encrypted S3 Bucket using URL in Java

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, amazon-s3

```
private static final String bucketName = "imagebucket";
private static final BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("secret_id", "secret_pass");
private static final String destinationFolder = "images/";

private static AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3Client
                    .builder()
                    .withRegion("us-east-2")
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                    .build();

@RequestMapping("/image")
public String uploadToBucketAndReturnUrl(byte[] fileByteArray, String extension)
{
    //generate a UUID hash
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    String randomUUIDString = uuid.toString();
    String imageHash = randomUUIDString + "." + extension;
    String filePath = destinationFolder+imageHash;

    try
    {
        File tf = File.createTempFile("image", "." + extension); 
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileByteArray));
        ImageIO.write(image, extension, tf);
        s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, filePath, tf));   
    }

    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return the url
    String imageUrl = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/" + bucketName + "/" + filePath;
    return imageUrl;
}
```

I have a function that will upload an image to my encrypted bucket and return a URL. Now I need to create a function that will take in the URL and retrieve the image from the bucket, and I'm unsure how to procceed.

Comment: If you want to use a private S3 bucket I would recommend using the AmazonS3Client to return a signed url to the resource.  You can also used signed urls for uploading.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html

Comment: Are there any alternatives to re-writing the original function or should I just go ahead and try re-writing it using a presigned URL